# definition of an conformal map confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

We said that a conformal map preserves angles, but in lecture we should that the map $f(z) = z^2$ doubles the angle by while mapping line segments to line segments ($z = re^{i\theta}, z^2 = r^2 e^{i2\theta}$), this doesn't preserve the angle but the lecturer stated that the map is indeed conformal for $z \not = 0$.

I don't understand the definition of "preserving" the angle, seeing as $z^2$ in my eyes, doubles the angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conformal map preserves angles at all points $w$ where $f'(w) \neq 0$.

The basic idea is that if $f'(w) \neq 0$ then near the point $w$, the map is $f(z) = f(w) + f'(w)(z-w) + o(z-w)$ near $w$.

That is, $f(z) - f(w) \approx f'(w) (z-w)$ near the point $w$. The map locally is approximated by multiplication by the complex number $f'(w)$ (ignoring the constants $f(w)$ and $w$, which are just translating the input and output).

Now multiplication by $f'(w)$ is a product of a dilation by $|f'(w)|$ and a rotation by $\mathrm{arg}(f'(w))$.

Both dilations and rotations preserve angles.

---

This doesn't hold at $z = 0$ for $f(z) = z^2$ since $f'(0) = 0$, i.e. $0$ is a critical point.

When $f'(z) = 0$, then the local approximation doesn't start constant plus a linear term, but rather constant plus some higher order term, so the above argument is invalid.

Comment: I don't understand how it preserves angles though, I mean $f(z) = z^2$ is doubling the angle.

Comment: Actually, $f(z) = z^2$ only doubles angles for pairs of lines through the origin. Any other pair of lines, the angle will be preserved. I'll add some more detail in my answer.